# In asp.net what is the difference between ValidationProperty and ValidationPropertyAttribute metadata attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, attributes

Simple Question, but I can't seem to find the answer.

What is the difference between the `ValidationProperty` and `ValidationPropertyAttribute` metadata attributes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing, attributes can be used with their full name or without the `Attibute` suffix. The comiler will automatically add `Attribute` if it can't find an attribute with the *short* name.

> Note   By convention, all attribute names end with the word "Attribute" to distinguish them from other items in the .NET Framework. However, you do not need to specify the attribute suffix when using attributes in code. For example, you can specify HelpAttribute as follows:
>   `[Help("http://localhost/MyClassInfo")] // [Help] == [HelpAttribute]`

From
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(v=vs.71).aspx#vcwlkattributestutorialanchor2

Comment: Thank you so much.  This was really confusing for me.  Any idea why they would do it like this?

Comment: @Chris, to save you a bit of typing and make the code cleaner. You know it's an attribute because of the usage, so why state the obvious and make you type `Attribute` every time.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. You can use both `[ValidationProperty]` and `[ValidationPropertyAttribute]`. Ending 'Attribute' is optional. The same is for all other system attributes.